# figure environment doesn't work in poster latex

Tags: beamerposter

I am creating a poster and for some reason, this doesn't work:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig/pic.pdf}\\
   \caption{BLAHBALH}
\end{figure}
```

It doesn't produce any error, it only doesn't show anything in the poster. However this works:

```
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig/pic.pdf}\\
\end{center}
```

Why?

Comment: `figure` is a floating environment and therefore no use on a poster. Why do you want to use a `figure` here? The second approach is just fine. If you need a caption, use the `\captionof{figure}{<caption text>}` command.

Comment: I realize this is ancient, but since it showed up on the front page: `figure` works fine in a `beamer`+`beamerposter` poster (at least it did in my test), is the tag accurate? If this was a recent question I'd ask for a complete example, but I guess the above comment was sufficient answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the tikzfigure environment:

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[Insert Caption Here]
      \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{filename.png}
\end{tikzfigure}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! While this would work in the `tikzposter` class, based on the tag the OP appears to have used the `beamerposter` package, where it would not work. (I'm not sure he actually used `beamer` + `beamerposter` though, as the normal `figure` environment works fine there, so it's a bit unclear to me what happened for him.)

Comment: Yeah, your right, I forgot about that.